# Upload file using OpenStack Cinder

Tags: 12.04, openstack

Can we upload file using OpenStack Cinder?

I have installed OpenStack via DevStack and has no Swift enabled.

Answer (score -1):

OpenStack cinder (Block Storage) provides the software to create and centrally manage a service that provisions storage in the form of block devices known as Cinder volumes on virtual machines active on cloud. if you are working on any one of the VM and if you store any file on that VM, that file will be stored as cinder volume. I think that's what you mean by upload.

Comment: Can I upload any file using Cinder? ANy API for that?